# How to take continuous back up of linux gnome terminal logs? commands and output of that command

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome-terminal

I want to take continuous backup of logs being printed in my linux terminal. Is it possible that whenever something will be printed in my terminal, it will automatically get printed into some text file with time stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `script` command ie

```
script log.txt
```

at the start of your session. You can also add this to your bash profile so that it starts when you open a terminal etc. You need to use

```
script -a log.txt
```

to append. Don't try and cat it or tail it while in the session, you need to **CTRL-D** then have a look at what got logged.